# finding triangulars from array

Tags: c++

zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers is given. A triplet (P, Q, R) is triangular if  and

```
A[P] + A[Q] > A[R], 
A[Q] + A[R] > A[P], 
A[R] + A[P] > A[Q].
```

For example, consider array A such that

```
A[0] = 10    A[1] = 2    A[2] =  5
A[3] =  1    A[4] = 8    A[5] = 20
```

Triplet (0, 2, 4) is triangular.
Write a function

```
int triangle(const vector<int> &A);
```

that, given a zero-indexed array A consisting of N integers, returns 1 if there exists a triangular triplet for this array and returns 0 otherwise.

Assume that:

N is an integer within the range [0..100,000];
each element of array A is an integer within the range [-2,147,483,648..2,147,483,647].
For example, given array A such that

A[0] = 10    A[1] = 2    A[2] =  5
A[3] =  1    A[4] = 8    A[5] = 20
the function should return 1, as explained above. Given array A such that
A[0] = 10    A[1] = 50    A[2] =  5
A[3] =  1
the function should return 0.
Expected worst-case time complexity:
Expected worst-case space complexity: O(1)

Comment: Sounds like homework. Where have you got so far?

Comment: Actually, it is homework!  I originally was planning to sort it but because of the requirement of 0 < P < Q < R < N it seems that sorting is out of the questions.  I have no real idea of where to start from there.

Comment: Why are you using zero-indexed C-style arrays in your question, yet asking for a function accepting a vector as an argument? :)

Comment: You left out your time complexity requirements. If there is no requirement you can just look at each possible set of 3 elements and do the checks on them, but that is O(N³)

Comment: Nedlinin: what requirement? @Shaktal: vectors are subscriptable

Comment: How can the space complexity be O(1) when the array (resp. vector) A has N elements?

Comment: Because the array has been allocated already and handed to you, so the function shouldn't need to allocate a copy.

Comment: @Jiri: passed by reference. And input arguments doesn't count anyway.

Comment: Please consider what Shaktal said. Dumping your homework like this without showing what efforts you made doesn't encourage us to help. Showw us you're stuck, not you slack.

Comment: Is this a C++ course or a set theory course?

Comment: @yi_H: when the elements are stored in an array of size N, then the space complexity of the algorithm is at least O(N). O(1) complexity is independent of N, e.g. when the data needs constant amount of memory or are read from a stream - and this is not the case here.

Comment: @Jiri: think about what happens when you compile this program in it's current form. On the stack you only allocate a pointer for the array.

Comment: @Jiri yi_H is right. The array is given, so it already takes up space, the algorithm doesn't need to take more than a constant amount. It would only take O(N) if it made a copy of the array, or a new array whose size is linearly proportional to N

Comment: @PaulPRO and yi_H: I googled and it seems that the space complexity is a matter of definition: (1) either it is the total space, e.g. the tape length of a Turing machine, then it would be O(N) or (2) it is the additional space to the input, then it would be O(1). OK, learned again something. Thank you both!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `O(N³)` is acceptable time complexity then the Pseudocode below should work. If you have stricter time  complexity requirements then you'll have to specify them.

```
for (P in A){
    for (Q in A){
        for (R in A){
            if(A[P] > 0 && A[Q] > 0 && A[R] > 0){
                if(A[P] > A[R] - A[Q] && A[Q] > A[P] - A[R] && A[R] > A[Q] - A[P]){
                    return 1;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
return 0;
```

The reasoning behind the if statements is this:

Since the ints can be anything up to max int you have to deal with overflow. Adding them together could cause a weird error if there are two very large ints in the array. So instead we test if they are positive and then rewrite the formulae to do the same checks, but with subtraction. We don't need to do anything if any of the values are negative or 0, since:

```
Assume x <= 0
Assume x+y > z
Assume x+z > y
Then y > z and z > y which is a contradiction
```

So no negative or zero valued ints will be a part of a triple

Comment: Nice treatment of large ints (+1). Should not the test be a conjunction instead of disjunction?

Comment: @Jiri, yes you are correct, that was a mistake. I edited it now.

Comment: Is a long guaranteed to be longer 32-bits?  If so I would just use longs for the inequality comparisons given that this is homework and doesn't need to be efficient.  Also I don't understand your little proof; what is the motivation for the 2nd and 3rd assumptions and why does this contradiction tell us that "we don't need to do anything if any of the values are negative or 0".  In fact, I have a counter-example to your claim: if the array has a negative number, the function needs to return a value or 0 or 1, therefore the function needs to do _something_.

Comment: Ok I get it now.  You proved that if an element is non-positive then it can not be part of a triangular triplet, which justifies the 'if(A[P] > 0 && A[Q] > 0 && A[R] > 0)' part of your code.  But I wouldn't claim that "we don't need to do anything".

Comment: @DavidGrayson I meant it as in there doesn't need to be any special handling of negative values inside the loop.

Answer (score 6):

**First claim**

First of all there is no point to take into account non-positive number. There's no chance you may achieve the triangle inequalities if at least one of the numbers is negative or zero. This is obvious, nevertheless here is the proof:

Assume A, B, C obey the triangle inequality, whereas C <= 0. Then you have

- A + C > B. Hence A > B.
- B + C > A. Hence B > A.

(contradiction).

**Second claim**

Suppose A, B, C obey the triangle inequalities, whereas C is the largest among A,B,C. Then for each A2 and B2 between A,B respectively and C - they will also obey triangle inequality.

In other words:

- A,B,C obey triangle inequalities.
- C >= A
- C >= B
- C >= A2 >= A
- C >= B2 >= B
- Then A2,B2,C also obey triangle inequalities.

The proof is trivial, enough to write the inequalities explicitly.

The consequence of this is that if C is the largest number for which you want to find the triangle inequality - **you should check only two largest numbers from the set not exceeding C**, and check if A + B > C.

**Third claim**

If 0 < A <= B <= C don't obey triangle inequalities, then C >= A*2.

The proof is trivial as well: A + B <= C, hence A + A <= C, hence C >= A*2

**The algorithm**

1. Pick 2 largest numbers B and C (B <= C).
2. Pick the largest number A not exceeding B, such that

   - A <= B <= C.
   - Make sure it's not the same element as B,C
   - Take into account only positive integers.
   - If unable to pick such a number - done. (No triangulars).
3. Check if A,B,C obey the triangle inequality. Test if A + B > C. (done if they do).
4. Discard the largest number C. Substitute C = B, then B = A.
5. Go to step 2.

**Fourth claim**

The above algorithm is logarithmic in the maximum integer size. In other words, its linear in the data type bitness. It's worst-case complexity is **independent** on the input length. Hence - it's O(1) in the input length.

**Proof:**

At every iteration (that does not find the solution) we have A <= C/2. After two such iterations A becomes *the new C*. This means that after every two iterations the largest number becomes at least 2 times smaller.

Obviously this gives us the upper bound of the number of the iterations. Gives our integers are limited by 31 bit (we ignore negatives), whereas the minimum interesting largest C is 1, this gives us no more that 2 * (31 - 1) = **60 iterations**.

Comment: Step 2 is a linear search, unless you can pre-sort the array, since it's looking at all other entries.

Comment: @Dave S: Yes, I mean the algorithm complexity is O(N). Sorry.

Comment: what do you mean with "data type bitness"?

Answer (score 0):

Sorting would be very cool, but const vector and O(1) space requirements doesn't allow it.

(because this is homework) Some hint: triangular numbers are close to each other.

Comment: I'm pretty sure an `O(N**2)` solution is possible.

Answer (score 0):

A hint: if you pick just two members of the array then what are the limits on the possible value of the third member of a triangular triplet?  Any number outside those limits can be rejected immediately.

Answer (score 0):

There are many in-place sorts; use one of them to sort the array - say comb sort for smaller ones (time complexity O(N^2)) or heap sort (complexity O(N log(N)).

Once you have sorted array, problem should be whether there is a set of 3 numbers where `A[X] > (A[X-1] + A[X+1]) / 2` i.e. middle number is greater than average of preceding & succeeding numbers (sadly this is a guess, I don't have a real basis - if its incorrect I hope someone corrects me, but there should be some good way to redefine the 'triangle' requirement to be more easily checked).

Now you just have an O(1) iteration over the sorted array to check whether the condition is true, hence overall complexity will be that of the sorting algorithm (best case N logN)

Comment: We can't do an in-place sort because the vector is const.

Comment: And you can't make a copy because that would violate the space constraint.

Comment: Completely missed that its a const vector, sorting would have been so much easier :(

Comment: This fails with the numbers 1, 5, and 8. 5 > 4.5(which is 8+1/2), but 1+5 < 8.